# Read csv logfiles with different headers/columns

Tags: c#, winforms, performance, csv, datatable

I need to read multiple csv files and merge them. The merged data is used for generating a chart (with the .NET chart control).

So far I've done this with a simple streamreader and added everything to one DataTable:

```
while (sr.Peek() > -1)
{
  strLine = sr.ReadLine();
  strLine = strLine.TrimEnd(';');
  strArray = strLine.Split(delimiter);
  dataTableMergedData.Rows.Add(strArray);
}
```

But now there is the problem, that the logfiles can change. As you can see here, newer logfiles have got additional columns: [image: logfile schema]

My current procedure doesn't work now and I'm asking for advice how to do this. Performance is important due to the fact, that every logfile contains about 1500 lines and up to 100 columns and the logfiles get merged up to a one-year-period (equals 365 files).

I would do it that way: Creating a DataTable, which should contain all data at the end and reading each logfile into a seperate DataTable. After each read operation I would add the seperate DataTable to the "big" DataTable, check if columns have changed and add the new columns if they did.

But I'm afraid that using DataTables would affect the performance.

Note: I'm doing this with winforms, but I think that doesn't matter anyway.

**Edit:** Tried [CsvReader](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/9258/A-Fast-CSV-Reader) but this is about 4 times slower than my current solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After hours of testing I did it the way I described it in the question:

Firstly I created a `DataTable` which should contain all the data at the end. Then I am going through all logfiles by a foreach-loop and for every logfile I create another `DataTable` and fill it with the csv-data from the logfile. This table gets added to the first `DataTable` and no matter if they have different columns, they get added properly.

This may costs some performance compared to a simple `StreamReader`, but It is more easier to extend and still faster than the LumenWorks CsvReader.